# Error Installing Sphinx Requires libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, sphinx, libmysql

I'm trying to install Sphinx Search on CENTOS 6.5 x86_64 standard server but am experiencing an issue. It throws error Requires libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit). I already have libmysqlclient_16 installed. Please I would appreciate any help on this.

Below is result of locate libmysql command on command line

```
# locate libmysql
/home/cpeasyapache/src/php-5.4.27/ext/mysqli/mysqli_libmysql.h
/home/cpeasyapache/src/php-5.4.27/ext/mysqli/tests/mysqli_stmt_send_long_data_packet_size_libmysql.phpt
/home/cpeasyapache/src/php-5.4.27/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_libmysql_compat.h
/home/cpeasyapache/src/php-5.4.27/ext/pdo_mysql/tests/pdo_mysql___construct_options_libmysql.phpt
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.16
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.18
/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.18.0.0
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.a
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.a
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlservices.a
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/mariadb/libmysql.so
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/mariadb/libmysqlclient.a
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/mariadb/libmysqlclient.so
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/mariadb/libmysqlclient_r.so
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15.0.0
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.15
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.15.0.0
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/54/include/php/ext/mysqli/mysqli_libmysql.h
/usr/local/cpanel/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.16
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqli/mysqli_libmysql.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_libmysql_compat.h
```

Below is installation results

```
# yum install http://sphinxsearch.com/files/sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.supremebytes.com
 * extras: mirrors.centarra.com
 * updates: mirror.oss.ou.edu
Setting up Install Process
sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm                          |  10 MB     00:06
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-Aoxjte/sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm: sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-Aoxjte/sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package sphinx.x86_64 0:2.1.7-1.rhel6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libodbc.so.2()(64bit) for package: sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpq.so.5()(64bit) for package: sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postgresql-libs.x86_64 0:8.4.20-1.el6_5 will be installed
---> Package sphinx.x86_64 0:2.1.7-1.rhel6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64
---> Package unixODBC.x86_64 0:2.2.14-12.el6_3 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64 (/sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
Error: Package: sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64 (/sphinx-2.1.7-1.rhel6.x86_64)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that due to missing mysql dependency issue in 64bit CENTOS it wasn't possible for me to install through YUM. I installed Sphinx from Source tarball package using the command below:

```
# wget http://sphinxsearch.com/files/sphinx-2.1.7-release.tar.gz
# tar -zxf 'sphinx-2.1.7-release.tar.gz'
# cd sphinx-2.1.7-release
# mkdir /usr/local/sphinx
# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/sphinx
# make
# make install
```

Comment: This just helped me out loads. I was getting the same issues, with the same dependant files, but with CentOS 6.